# Counting Queen's paths on a rectangular chessboard

Tags: code-golf, grid, chess

### Task

Given two positive integers \$m,n\$, imagine a chessboard of size \$m \times n\$. A chess queen is on the upper-left corner. In how many ways can it reach the lower-right corner, by moving only right, down, or diagonally right-down (possibly moving many steps at once, because it's a queen)?

The resulting 2D sequence is [A132439](http://oeis.org/A132439).

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
m n result
1 1      1
1 2      1
1 3      2
1 4      4
1 5      8
2 2      3
2 3      7
2 4     17
2 5     40
3 3     22
3 4     60
3 5    158
4 4    188
4 5    543
5 5   1712
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>94</s> <s>91</s> <s>64</s> 54 bytes

```hs
1!1=1;m!n=sum[m!(n-x)+(m-x)!n+(m-x)!(n-x)|x<-[1..m+n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYuxCoMwFEV/5WZLkAgZuljtXrBTxxCK0IJa31NMgg7@e2pLB5d7OAdu2/j3axiSFApFgSsH6MsByQhTmTMJrnwkS0KyXlUmaV/Bf/7atpbamjynjJ1L1HSMCtRMtwemGO5hrhk28jLOTw/r23GB7ESvsKFHqfH9npzbtTto@gA)

Initially a boring port of the comment on OEIS

-27 from some tricks off dingledooper's answer

-10 from Christian Sievers

Comment: I think you can replace `max m n` with `m+n`

Comment: @ChristianSievers seems like it, and with that the `m*n>0` check was also unnecessary, ty!

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 75 bytes

@xnor's idea which is 2 bytes smaller than the one below. Returns `True` for `1 1`.

```python
f=lambda m,n:sum(f(m-i,n)+f(m,n-i)+f(m-i,n-i)for i in range(1,n|m))or m>0<n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3NDoIwEITvfYq92cZibAsXIr6KqRGkCV0aKCEmvnsdPEzmm/1NnzzObEsZusnH58tT1NyuW5SDjFXQrM4AzVX4w1EBDvNCgQLT4vndS6P5G5VCMd6vNy77GKaeTCtwjJg6ij7JwFljfn8ETluW6rKmKWR5opNSgtKC/vETC0oVQ0YYspCDaqgRFtkiW2SL7MAO7MA1vIY31PwA)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>79</s> 77 bytes

```python
f=lambda m,n:(m==n==1)+sum(f(m-i,n)+f(m,n-i)+f(m-i,n-i)for i in range(1,n+m))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3NCoMwEITveYq9mWAsJNGLkGcplmpdMGvQiPTp7djDsN/sz2z@lnkVf11TXIb0eg@UrPQ6xSgxOlPvR9KTTg1bMTXASsN/uDvAad2IiYW2QT6jdlbqZMx1zryM5HqFOBKKlIasWYrF3vlkyUfR5rHnhYuuqDJGUd4wv3/hAAmOnHLkoQC1UKc8vIf38B4@gAM4gFvUFrWj7gc)

Comment: I think the 77-byter is surely correct. The correctness is clear and it will end in finite time because n+m is decreasing.

Comment: Yes, you're definitely right. It probably just takes longer for larger inputs.

Comment: Here's a way to shave two bytes off the base case for the first one, with `True` for `1`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3NDoIwEITvfYq92cZibAsXIr6KqRGkCV0aKCEmvnsdPEzmm/1NnzzObEsZusnH58tT1NyuW5SDjFXQrM4AzVX4w1EBDvNCgQLT4vndS6P5G5VCMd6vNy77GKaeTCtwjJg6ij7JwFljfn8ETluW6rKmKWR5opNSgtKC/vETC0oVQ0YYspCDaqgRFtkiW2SL7MAO7MA1vIY31PwA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @xnor Clever idea; thanks for the improvement!

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 36 bytes

```
{(x~1 1)+/o'x-/:{|/'~x,'-/'x}#1_+!x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxFzEsKgzAUheF5VpHSQhQr8eZRJZl0HyK1k0BpQRAHEatrb+7NoLOPw88JbiviARzKSk4i1tJtXymOeBW1FHE/w6M6xZ2x4Joq3Nnitku/HrMLPPpxevtiDM/Xx0e/+rkcdrb06WvgnANR/amRimiQhmiRXaLKrSZS2xKxhUxsTZOoKVCKiMEtrykAi2cGV+gy02oN/tpEaEGxH40JO4w=)

`!x` odometer

`+` transpose

`1_` drop the first

`{` `}#` filter

`|/'~x,'-/'x` either element or their difference is 0

`x-/:` subtract each right

`o'` recur each

`+/` sum

`(x~1 1)` does `x` match `1 1`? use as initial value for the sum

Answer (score 3):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 92 bytes

Boring port of the Haskell answer.

```erlang
f(1,1)->1;f(M,N)->lists:sum([f(M,N-X)+f(M-X,N)+f(M-X,N-X)||X<-lists:seq(1,max(M,N)),M*N>0]).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYwxC8IwEEb3/oobc5oTO7jUkr2Fdi6UIkESCTRVk4oO@e/1KAoO3vR43/FMGPV0IRPPwd3mJVusyGWOpPKjFY1smUYX51jEhxf9qqjDLQN1vH6BXUpdSZ9fc@eK16@1gLLZtGo/4G7x2k3ihEAqAz53LZ7BzUb0PVhRSagRUoIaSoLf0gFhYF/981x9Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 40 bytes

```
ＮθＦＮＦθ⊞υ∨¬υΣΦυ∨∨⁼ι÷μθ⁼κ﹪μθ⁼⁻ικ⁻÷μθ﹪μθＩ⊟υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY67DoMwDEV3vsKjI6UjE2MfEgMUqV@QAhUReZAQ8/tpFJBaYXnxOdeW@0n43goVY20WCi3p9@jRsar4WA/4DxmDzByDjtYJicPTY2sDEuPwIo0PqUIK7iL13ZFQK0oOtQk3uclhRM3BsZQ/3MyhsQMpe4ifaaShvDsntg@nK@fVXFXReWkCXsUasLNLei7BGEso42VTXw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the number of columns.

```
ＦＮ
```

Loop over the rows.

```
Ｆθ
```

Loop over each column.

```
⊞υ∨¬υ
```

The first result is always `1`...

```
ΣΦυ∨∨⁼ι÷μθ⁼κ﹪μθ⁼⁻ικ⁻÷μθ﹪μθ
```

... otherwise find the existing results that are a Queen's move away, take the total, and push that to the list of results. The list therefore simulates a matrix, requiring its index to be divided or taken modulo the number of columns as appropriate to compare with the loop variables.

```
Ｉ⊟υ
```

Output the last result calculated.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>60</sup> 50 bytes

```
_2{(],1#.]#~(#:#)(0=*/*-/)@:-"1(#:i.@#))^:(*/@[)&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc7NCsIwDADgu08RVnDr2LqmP24UBgPBkyevoh7EoV58AMFXr3ONkAWSw0f@njFT@Qh9gBwq0BCmrBVsD/tdvJh3capQqJP4FCIIWei@bMq6kUOoM5zooQYh5TkUZTMc5RqjXN2u9xcg9DBOFWGOJRqOhtBydISOY0foOdoZzXJnS7jYiX91/JAm9Pyl9JOl@YQbTcjH0XeknmGX0KXWhN5ZQt7ZYjrlfxq/)